# How to do "android drawing pattern to unlock" using COCOS2D API

Tags: android, cocos2d-iphone

I want to do a task which is very similar to "Android Drawing Pattern to Unlock", where in there will be circular images in a GridView and straight lines connecting the images will be drawn dynamically based on user touch. Please suggest me preferably with code snippets.TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actully, you didn't write your code into the question .so I think you are developing Android Application with COCOS2D first time.

Here is some awesome example links that may Help you to learn this.

1)[COCOS2D Basic Game](http://dan.clarke.name/2011/04/how-to-make-a-simple-android-game-with-cocos2d/)

2)[COCOS2D  MUltiplatform](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/Chapter_1_-_How_to_Create_a_New_cocos2d-x_project_on_multi-platforms)

If you want help regarding code please post your code here.

Comment: buddy, I have gone through most of the tutorials and even have developed some apps using cocos2d. But, this task is taking pretty long time. but, anyway you have suggested some good links. Thanks for that...

Comment: @Manjunath I already wrote this ..Please writedown your code where you facing error.

Comment: dude, I am not facing any error. But, I want to add the feature of drawing straight line between the images (in a GridView) through finger touch and drag. I have already created GridView of sprite images. Like, need to add some code in 'ccTouchesMoved' method that draws a straight line from starting sprite to current location.

Comment: bro,if draw a line is from your userend then you can use the CANVAS class for Draw

Comment: :) No dude. I could have done that. But, as I am using COCOS2D API for the screen, I can't mix canvas with it. Have to write using cocos2d packages.